# Default Methods and the Compile Time error: The inherited method Horse.identifyMyself() cannot hide the public abstract method in Flyer

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, default

The following query is based on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) official Oracle documentation. In this document under the heading "Interface Methods", under sub-section "Instance methods are preferred over interface default methods.", there are a few classes defined as follows:

```
public class Horse {
    public String identifyMyself() {
        return "I am a horse.";
    }
}

public interface Flyer {
    default public String identifyMyself() {
        return "I am able to fly.";
    }
}

public interface Mythical {
    default public String identifyMyself() {
        return "I am a mythical creature.";
    }
}

public class Pegasus extends Horse implements Flyer, Mythical {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Pegasus myApp = new Pegasus();
        System.out.println(myApp.identifyMyself());
    }
}
```

Everything is fine and the rule holds that inherited instance methods from super class are preferred over inherited default methods from super interfaces; however, whenever I drop the `public` access modifier from the method `Horse.identifyMyself()`, I get the following compile time error:

```
The inherited method Horse.identifyMyself() cannot hide the public abstract method in Mythical
```

Honestly, I am not able to fully reason out this compilation error. The possible explanation I am able to think is that since we are reducing the visibility of `Horse.identifyMyself()` from `public` to package-private it is failing in hiding `public` method inherited from the interface(s). If this is correct, then why compiler is giving a new error message, it could have simply retained the old, well-known message: "`Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method...`"

Another query is that why compiler is referring to `Mythical.identifyMyself()` as "abstract method" when it is declared as `default` method given especially when `abstract` and `default` are mutually exclusive key words!

Thanks in advance for your patience and inputs.

Sincerely,
Nawazish

Answer (score 0):

Pegasus extends Horse, and since it does not have it's own identifyMyself() method, it inherits the one defined in Horse, which is now private, since you removed the public from it.  Now, because Pegasus also implements Mythical, which defines method identifyMyself as public, Pegasus has to have a public version of this method, but it only has a private one, so you get this error.  Unlike in C++, you cannot change (reduce) the visibility of an overridden method from public to private (or protected).

Comment: So what could be the possible reason for using the word "hiding" in the compilation error. Why Horse.identifyMyself() is unable to "hide" equivalent method in the interface(s)?

Comment: Because if you have an object whose type is Mythical, the signature of the interface says that there is a public method identifyMyself(), but the concrete implementation only has a private one, so it does not adhere to the interface definition.  So because you're trying to take a public method and make it private, since private methods can't be called outside the class, you are "hiding" the method.

Comment: Can you clarify the following statement, "object whose type is Mythical, the signature of the interface says that there is a public method identifyMyself(), but the concrete implementation only has a private one, so it does not adhere to the interface definition."
Horse is not a concrete implementation of Mythical (or even Flyer for that matter), so there is no question of "it does not adhere to the interface definition." The same reasoning goes with "you're trying to take a public method and make it private," - I am not taking any public method from Mythical i'face into Horse implementation.

Comment: Right, Horse does not implement Mythical, but Pegasus does, so Pegasus does have to adhere to interface.  Pegasus has a identifyMyself method, which it inherits from Horse.  So, since Horse does not implement Mythical, it can have a private method, but in Pegasus, this method cannot be private, because it implements Mythical.  When I said "object whose type is Mythical", I meant "a variable defined as type Mythical".  This variable could hold an instance of Pegasus, or any other class that implements Mythical, but the class has to have a public identifyMyself method.

Answer (score 0):

1. The inherited method `Horse.identifyMyself()` cannot hide the public abstract method in Mythical

   All methods declared in an interface are implicitly public.

   All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly
   public, so you can omit the public modifier.

   Your class Pegasus is extending Horse and implementing Flyer, Mythical which
   has same method `identifyMyself()` so method from class Horse will be preferred
   but you are reducing the visibility of Horse.identifyMyself() to default when
   you removing public from it, due which you are getting above compilation
   error and it will be removed once you make `Horse.identifyMyself()` method
   public too.
2. since we are reducing the visibility of `Horse.identifyMyself()` from public to package-private it is failing in hiding public method inherited from the interface(s)

   When you will make it private then your class Pegasus  will not have access
   to it.
3. Another query is that why compiler is referring to Mythical.identifyMyself() as "abstract method" when it is declared as default method given especially when abstract and default are mutually exclusive key words!

   When compiler is referring to `Mythical.identifyMyself()` as "abstract method",
   it is just overriding.